# Event for row deselect on JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using the JQGrid and have an "Add new" button defined.

```
$(gridId).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pagerId, {
    caption: "Add Record",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-add",
    onClickButton: function (id) {
        var newId = -1;
        $('#addButton').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        var datarow = { Id: newId, 'Active': true, 'Location': '', 'LabCode': '', 'Crops': '', 'LabManager': '', 'MarkerChoice': '', 'AllowPlates': '', 'AllowTape': '' };
        var su = jQuery(gridId).jqGrid('addRowData', newId, datarow, "last");
        if (su) {
            $(gridId).jqGrid('setSelection', newId);
        }
    },
    position: "last",
    id: "addButton"
});
```

As you can see, when the button is clicked it disables so it cannot be clicked again.  My problem is that when a user clicks add and then hits esc I need to re-enable the add button:

```
$('#addButton').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

But I'm not sure where to do that?  Is there a row deselected event or equivalent that I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `onSelectRow` method.  You could capture the selected row and if it changes or is -1 you can call your `removeClass()` code.

```
var lastSel;
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
...
   onSelectRow: function(id){ 
      if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
         ... 
         lastSel=id; 
      } 
   },
...
});
```

Edit: To trap the ESC key:

```
/* could use window or a specific element if required */
$(window).keydown(function(e) {   // or keyup, keypress
        if (e.keyCode == '27') {  // ESC
            e.preventDefault();
            // do something with the grid
        }
});
```

Comment: Unfortuantely onSelectRow doesn't fire when pressing the esc key.

Comment: Misread your question, didn't realize you only wanted to do something when ESC was pressed.  See my answer edit for a possible solution.

Comment: I found the same thing just before I read your answer.  Seems like a bit of a hack, but it works!  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately any custom key navigation is always going to look awful.  I try and avoid it at all costs but often transitioning DOS based users into web users requires some compromise.  Good luck.